# how can i change color using button?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

This is a bootstrap color picker. I want to use the button inside the div, when I click the button, it shows the color chart and changes the background color of div. How can I do that?

```
    <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-sm-4   border  border-primary  picker">
             <!--    add   a  button here -->
               <button class=" btn btn-primary"> clolor </button>
                 <h4> colopicker</h4>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-sm-8">
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="src/colorPick.js"></script>
       <script>
            $(".picker").colorPick({
                'initialColor': 'onColorSelected',
                'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
                'onColorSelected': function() {
                    console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color)
                    this.element.css({
                        'backgroundColor': this.color
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: `'backgroundColor': this.color` change it to  `'background': this.color`

Comment: Your code is fine. You not have added CSS link

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 button into div, and call click button event to show the color chart.
Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
<div class="row">
            <div class=" col-sm-4   border  border-primary  picker">
            <!--    add   a  button here -->
                <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Choose color">
                <h4> colopicker</h4>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-sm-8">
            </div>
    </div>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btnShow').on('click', function(){
        $(".picker").colorPick({
                'initialColor': 'onColorSelected',
                'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
                'onColorSelected': function() {
                    console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color)
                    this.element.css({
                        'backgroundColor': this.color
                    });
                }
            });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

check it out , working example of your code

https://codepen.io/de-co/pen/xxxgKby

```
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Flat-HTML5-Palette-Color-Picker-For-jQuery-colorPick-js/colorPick.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Flat-HTML5-Palette-Color-Picker-For-jQuery-colorPick-js/colorPick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-sm-4   border  border-primary  picker">
         <!--    add   a  button here -->
              <Button >colopicker</Button>
             <h4> colopicker</h4>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-sm-8">
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>

   <script>
     $('button').click(function(){

        $(".picker").colorPick({
            'initialColor': 'onColorSelected',
            'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
            'onColorSelected': function() {
                console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color)
               $('button').css({
                    'backgroundColor': this.color
                });
            }
        });
         });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Flat-HTML5-Palette-Color-Picker-For-jQuery-colorPick-js/colorPick.css">
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="row">
      <div class=" col-sm-4   border  border-primary ">
         <button class=" btn btn-primary picker"> clolor </button>
         <h4> colopicker</h4>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-sm-8 show_color">
        Show color
      </div>
   </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Flat-HTML5-Palette-Color-Picker-For-jQuery-colorPick-js/colorPick.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".picker").colorPick({
            'initialColor': 'onColorSelected',
            'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
            'onColorSelected': function() {
                console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color);
                /*this.element.css({
                    'backgroundColor': this.color
                });*/
                $('.show_color').css('backgroundColor',this.color);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have added document.ready in code and the CSS link for the color pallete as per the colorpick.js plugin https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Flat-HTML5-Palette-Color-Picker-For-jQuery-colorPick-js.html

The ready() method is used to make a function available after the document is loaded. Whatever code you write inside the $(document ).ready() method will run once the page DOM is ready to execute JavaScript code.

Comment: this code looks good, but it color-picker is also working outside of the button.   i want only the button will work to pick the color.   if you click outside button it will work like a button

Comment: check updated answer. Added picker class to button only

Comment: what you want on button clicking after selection color from pallete